# Regex: Kusto Query to fetch /extract text after a word

Tags: regex, azure-data-explorer, kql

Using Kusto Query, is there a way to extract or fetch the text after a word, "Measure".
For example in below string , i would like to fetch 2 values -

- cubeCount of Sales
- Number of Product Categories

string:

> SELECT NON EMPTY
> CrossJoin(Hierarchize(AddCalculatedMembers({DrilldownLevel({[Office
> View].[Office View].[All]})})), {[Measures].[cubeCount of
> Sales],[Measures].[Number of Product Categories]}) DIMENSION
> PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS , NON
> EMPTY
> Hierarchize(AddCalculatedMembers({DrilldownLevel({[Board].[Board].[All]})}))
> DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS
> FROM [EZI_NS] WHERE ([Entity].[Entity Schema].&[Total],[Date].[FY
> Year].&[FY2021],[Date].[FY Month Short].&[Jan],[Type].[Service
> Type].[All],[DateView].[DateView].&[Periodic]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE,
> FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS

Tried using regex, but unable to frame the query in the extract_all function.

Answer (score -1):

```
print txt = "SELECT NON EMPTY CrossJoin(Hierarchize(AddCalculatedMembers({DrilldownLevel({[Office View].[Office View].[All]})})), {[Measures].[cubeCount of Sales],[Measures].[Number of Product Categories]}) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS , NON EMPTY Hierarchize(AddCalculatedMembers({DrilldownLevel({[Board].[Board].[All]})})) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [EZI_NS] WHERE ([Entity].[Entity Schema].&[Total],[Date].[FY Year].&[FY2021],[Date].[FY Month Short].&[Jan],[Type].[Service Type].[All],[DateView].[DateView].&[Periodic]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS"
| project Measures = extract_all(@"\[Measures]\.\[(.*?)]", txt)
```

| Measures |
| --- |
| ["cubeCount of Sales","Number of Product Categories"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)